# Add a delay into an observer in R Shiny Leaflet Map

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

I have a [R Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) app which uses [leaflet](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) to render a map. As the user pans/zooms the map the app takes the map bounds and loads the relevant data using an [observe](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observe.html) function.

Here is a simplified version of the code, I've removed the code for selecting data because it is not relevant to this question.

```
# Start of Shiny Server Code
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
#Render Map
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      # set centre and extent of map
      setView(lng = -0.1, lat = 51.5, zoom = 9) %>%
      # set base map
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) 

  })
    observe({
        mapbounds <- input$mymap_bounds
        mapzoom <- input$mymap_zoom
        if(is.null(input$mymap_bounds)){
            # no map bounds so render nothing
        } 
        else if(mapzoom >= 11 & mapzoom <= 13){
            # Zoomed out so render one thing based on map bounds
        }
        else if(mapzoom >= 14){
            # Zoomed in so show render something else  based on map bounds
        }
        else
            # really zoomed out so render nothing

        # plot map
        proxy <- leafletProxy("mymap")
        # remove old layers
        proxy %>% clearShapes()
        #render new layers
        proxy %>% addPolygons(data = data)

      })
})
```

This works fine , but when a user pans/zooms rapidly across the map the app lags as it loads a whole string of different map views for each time the bounds of the map changes. This can cause crashes and downloads lots of unnecessary data.

Is is possible to adjust the observe function so that there is a short delay between observations, or even better a way to detect the difference between a user panning around and a user that has stopped panning and wants data loaded?

Comment: In shiny, I use a lot shinyjs::delay from https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs. It might work in your case.

Comment: poll for changes in map views/ boundaries. ..if a change Sys.sleep (n) before proxy maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shiny::debounce`:

e.g.

```
bound_change < - reactive({input$mymap_bounds})
bound_change_delay < - debounce(bound_change, 1000)

observe({
        mapbounds <- bound_change_delay()
```